# iOS 7 go into full screen mode (add to home screen button)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios7, fullscreen

Is there a way to go into fullscreen mode for iOS 7? Like when you add it to your homescreen and just your website pops up not the url bar and back bar etc? Does anyone know how to do this? Ive looked at a few posts saying you can't go into fullscreen mode anymore on iOS 7 but then i looked at the OpenAppMkt web app and it seems to be able to hide the url bar on iOS 7

Comment: This should just be a case of using the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag, as with other iOS versions. Have you tried that?

Comment: I actually havent, I just assumed it didn't work on ios 7 because of all the answers i read. Give me 5 minutes Ill see if it works

Comment: Wow it works... its even better then iOS 6 because you can press links and it won't redirect you to safari. I feel like an idiot, this is solved then haha.

Answer (score 18):

If you have access to the HTML, add the follow line to the HEAD:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Then refresh the page in Safari and re-add the page to your home screen. (If `content="no"` then it will not be displayed full-screen mode.)

Here is a link to Apple's [documentation on Safari MetaTags](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW3).